# Display entire file including spaces

Tags: php, file

I have several files on my vps and would like to display them on the internet. Without moving these files, I would just like to make a php page that gets the files and displays them.

The file in question looks like this (including spacing):

```
Player:         Alive: Score: Ping: Member of Team: 
test            No     1      41    test            
player_1        No     1      33    player_1       
bug*            Yes    1      37    bug*            
player 4        No     0      37    player 4
```

I've tried `echo readfile('/path/to/file.txt');`and with `file_get_contents`, however, none of the newlines or spacing are preserved.
Here is output with readfile():
`Player: Alive: Score: Ping: Member of Team: test No 1 41 test player_1 No 1 33 player_1 bug* Yes 1 37 bug* player 4 No 0 37 player 4 265`

Any hints on how to get this to show both spacing/tabs and newlines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<pre><?=htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file))?></pre>
```

Should be enough for you I believe. `htmlspecialchars()` is important to prevent any HTML-like content from being interpreted as HTML.

Comment: `htmlentities` breaks often with Unicode. `htmlspecialchars` should be sufficient.

Comment: @amphetamachine ah very true, fixed, I'm so used to using my shorthand function which itself calls `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<pre></pre>`. This way the original formatting will be preserved in html.

Comment: This works but at first I thought it didn't because I concatinated the pre's to the echo like this `echo '<pre>'.readfile('/home/duke/aa/servers/df/var/players-t.txt').'</pre>';` but putting the pre around the html works

Answer (score 1):

In an HTML document, newlines and multiple spaces are by default shown as a single space.

Wrap the output in `<pre>player: ...</pre>` or any other element with the CSS property `white-space: pre;`. For more information, refer to the CSS standard/.